# Keyboard Extension doesn't install the main app

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios-extensions

I have created new schemes for both main app and extension.
When I run the main app on device, it works as expected.
But when I run the keyboard extension it runs but it is not under debug, and if I remove the app previously then it wouldn't be installed.
Can anybody explain what's happened?

Comment: Please run your keyboard extension in scheme and check to debug and breakpoint check.

Comment: It doesn't stop at breakpoint. But I believe, if I fix the installation of main app, it fixes the extension debugging. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: you choose target when project run right ?

Comment: at that time not main project select but your keyboard extension select

Comment: then u give me response

Comment: Yep, I choose the scheme. For scheme there is a selected target - keyboard extension target.

Comment: What happen After keyboard extension?

Comment: XCode shows it's running, but there is even no the app on the device.

Comment: device in not working because your keyboard configure in setting menu

Comment: Device is ok. If I run the app, it installs and runs.

Comment: Goto Setting -> General-> Keyboard-> Keyboards-> Add New Keyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85187/discussion-between-rohit-suvagiya-and-mikhail-gasanov).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the main app target to build phase of keyboard extension scheme. When they are build together, everything works as expected.